# On how many different systems can you download your games?

Tags: ps3, ps4, psn

I though I knew how this work, but, after doing a bit of research I´m really confused. I have a PS3 and a PS4 where I use my regular account. If I bought another PS3 and PS4 I can use that account with those systems, and when I mean use my account, I mean to download my purchase games. So, that will be my limit right? 2 consoles per account. But, what if all those system brokes? I can't download my games anymore? I read something about going to the website and you remove the assing system to your account and you can continue using your account to download games in the future in other systems. So, as long as you have assing just two consoles to your account,it will be ok? Is this true?

Comment: At one point you could have up to 5 PS3s activated and people were using it to share content, pretty sure they changed it but I'm not sure what the exact rules are these days. You definitely can deactivate a console and then activate a new one though if that's what you're asking, not that clear...

Comment: @Probst Yeah, something like that was my question too. So, I can deactive and active any number of consoles I want? The only cons is that I can have only 2 active at the same time, is that right?

Comment: As far as I understand yes, however I've moved to PC gaming the past couple years so maybe there is someone with more recent experience who knows.

Comment: In case you registered max number of consoles and need to deactivate them you can go to https://account.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/liquid/cam/devices/device-media-list.action and login. There is a button "deactivate all systems"

Comment: @Zarathustrax not quite. There is a limit to how many times you can activate/deactivate a system over time. I think the PS4 has a 6 month wait between activation switches.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now (March 2016), you can have two Primary active PS3 systems and one Primary active PS4 system according to the [PSN FAQ page](https://www.playstation.com/en-ie/get-help/help-library/my-account/device-activation-deactivation/about-device-activation/).

You can sign into additional devices and download your games to play while logged in, but as soon as you log out the games become unlicensed for play by other users. I'm not sure how that works with concurrency though... eg, can you play against your self between two systems? IDK.

Note, even this page isn't always current but it's a good guide. For instance you can have three activations across PSP, Vita, and PS TV, not the two listed.

Comment: That's right, As of now (Jun2017) its' two primary PS3 max, and up to 5 overall (that means three more secundary), As of concurreny, you can't, to my knowlege, be signed in on more than one same device (ie two PS3), you can be signed in one PS3 and one PS4 but not two PS3 or 4; so you can't play against yourself. Furthermore, if you have an older PS acc (pre the 2007 hack) you can share all the games you bought back then in al five devices for all the users on those devices to play, even online (I still play my buddie's Burnout Paradise and Tekken Dark Ressurrecction with all my pals online)